# How to rotate image by 120 degree keeping its original shape

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have pattern image of 100x100 (vertical linings), i want to rotate it by 120deg. So i used following command.

```
  exec('convert -rotate "120" in.png out.png');
```

It rotates correctly, but i get white background on all for corners (a diamond pattern) because now pattern image is rotates.

[image]

But i want to get square 100x100 image with rotated pattern (120deg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough material to start with, so you kind of have to make some more by repeating what you have.

So, if we start with this as `stripes.png`:

[image]

You can do this:

```
convert stripes.png +clone +append +clone -append -rotate 120 -crop 100x100+70+70 result.png
```

and get:

[image]

The sequence `+clone +append` duplicates the original image and appends the copy to the right, making it into a new, wider image. The sequence `+clone -append` duplicates the new, wider image and appends the clone underneath making a single, new taller image. The image is now twice as wide and twice as high as the original. I then rotate it, and crop out of the middle region.

Comment: Ok so you meant to say i should use larger `in` image and create 100x100 from it so that it will fill. But still above works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly - I just didn't know you had a larger image so I made one for you :-) Good luck with your project!